# JavaScript testing that integrates best in Maven build lifecycle

Tags: java, javascript, maven

I want to introduce JS testing in a project and I want to choose between Jasmine or QUnit (or something third? maybe I'm missing the best one) and would like to know which of them is better in integrating with Maven:

- which can provide more useful configuration options in the project pom?
- which can I include as a Maven dependency and it to be available in some public repository?
- which has more active community (e.g. not the Jasmine project community, but the Jasmine Maven plugin project community)?

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently looking at the same thing.  Obviously Jasmine has tight integration (that's what it's for) while I didn't find another maven js testing solution I did come across [this post](http://liminescence.blogspot.jp/2010/11/tdd-with-javascript-jquery-qunit-and.html) on how to integrate QUnit directly with Maven.

Haven't played around with it yet, so don't know if it provides test statistics (run/fail/error) but you can always extract this from QUnit in other ways.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't you read the web-site about [Jasmine](http://searls.github.com/jasmine-maven-plugin/) there you will find the docs about the plugins and the configuration informations.

Comment: I know the website, that wasn't the question.. e.g. I don't know how's best to integrate QUnit in the build cycle, and If I know, whether it's better thatn Jasmine.